# Como puedo quitar la validacion de un input una vez que es correcto y no dar click cada vez al boton de enviar

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un formulario el cual tengo que realizar las validaciones en cada campo o  `input` lo tengo ya casi logrado, pero hay algunos detalles que me percate al momento de realizar las pruebas y vi que no esta al 100% todavía es por eso que acudí a esta comunidad para el apoyo, voy en listar los detalles que tengo.

1. Al momento de validar un campo ya sea vació o con alguna expresión regular, si es correcto el dato ingresado entonces quiero pasar al siguiente campo y que se desmarque el error sin estar dando clic al botón `submit`.
2. Me gustaría saber como puedo darle algo flotante al mensaje de error como el `tooltips` de `bootstrap`  para que no afecte el diseño, eso ya es algo a consideración no importa tanto.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#form {
width:50%;

}

#form .form-control {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.form-cont.success input{
  border-bottom: solid #01BF9B;
}

.form-cont.error input{
  border-bottom: solid #bf0101;
 
}

.form-cont small{
  color: #ffff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -12px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #bf0101;
}

.form-cont.error small{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO</h1>
    
    <!-- FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO-->
    
    <form id="form" class="mx-auto">
  <div class="col-auto form-cont">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="itNombre" placeholder="Nombre*" name="nombre">
    <small>Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto form-cont">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itEmail" placeholder="Email*" name="email">
    <small>Error message</small>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-auto form-cont">
    
    <textarea type="text"  class="form-control" id="itMensaje" placeholder="Mensaje*" name="mensaje"></textarea>
    <small>Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="checkInputs();">ENVIAR</button>
  </div>
</form>

 <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>



    
    <script>
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
const nombre = document.getElementById('itNombre');
const email = document.getElementById('itEmail');
const mensaje = document.getElementById('itMensaje');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
});


/* METODO PARA VALIDAR LOS INPUTS*/
function checkInputs(){

  const nombreValue = nombre.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const mensajeValue = mensaje.value.trim();

if (nombreValue =='') {
  setErrorFor(nombre, '¡Favor de llenar el campo Nombre!');
}else{
  setSuccessFor(nombre); 
}
if (emailValue =='') {
  setErrorFor(email, '¡Favor de llenar el campo Email!');
} else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
  setErrorFor(email, '¡Favor de validar!');
} else {
  setSuccessFor(email);
}

if (mensajeValue =='') {
  setErrorFor(mensaje, '¡Favor de llenar el campo Mensaje!');
} else{
  setSuccessFor(mensaje);
}

}

/* METODO PARA EJCUTAR LOS ERRORES*/
function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-cont error';
    small.innerText = message;
}
 
/* METODO PARA VALIDAR CON EXITO */
function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-cont success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
  return /^\w+([.-_+]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/.test(email);
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu quieres validaciones flotantes, creo que lo mejor es usar las validaciones nativas que justamente elevan un popup.

En tu caso solo necesitas usar:

- Atributo `required`: Para establecer que el input es obligatorio
- `type="email"`: Para obligar al input a solo aceptar el correo. Un correo valido puede ser sin punto `nombre@dominio`, si necesitas algo como `nombre@dominio.primerorden`, puedes usar:
- el atributo `pattern` que te permite una validación con expresiones regualares.

Por último puedes dar estilo CSS utilizando:

- `:invalid`
- `:valid`
- `:user-invalid`
- `:required`
- `:out-of-range`

```css
input:user-invalid, textarea:user-invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="mx-auto">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itNombre" placeholder="Nombre*" name="nombre" required>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="itEmail" placeholder="Email*" name="email" pattern="^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" required>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="itMensaje" placeholder="Mensaje*" name="mensaje"  required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-enviar">ENVIAR</button>

</form>
```